# Parsing from UTF-8 to XML in Python

Tags: python, list, utf-8, python-2.7, arabic

I'm a Python newbie, and I'm trying to write a Python script which parses a text-file (written in a particular format) into an XML file. The text-file is written in a non-European language, encoded in UTF-8 (written from right to left), and this alone is giving me some trouble.

Format of textfile:

```
{number}"|"{number}"|" {text in UTF-8}
```

An example of which is:

```
   1|2|حمد ހުރީ، عالم ތަކުގެ ވެރި اللَّه އަށެވެ
```

The initial problem was that when reading from the text, the ordering of the words are switched around in Python. 
If the text were to read:
1|2| ABC DEF, Python would display it as 1|2| DEF ABC
Which is obviously incorrect.

I'm using `file = open("text.txt")` and running `readlines()` on it to get the text.

In order to remedy this bug, I tried attempting to `split()` to separate the words and put them into a list and then to re-order them as desired, but in *this* case, there is probably a conversion error and I receive garbage characters. There is a problem in storing such UTF-8 characters into a Python list and retrieving them; the characters aren't preserved.

If this list-processing bug is fixed, then writing the XML file should be a piece of cake.

EDIT: If it helps, the language is Dhivehi, and the alphabet is Thaana.

Comment: Have you looked at [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open)? It *opens an encoded file using the given mode and return a wrapped version providing transparent encoding/decoding*.

Comment: I tried using codecs, it didn't help. The words in the sentence were still flipped around.

Comment: So what is the original problem? Latin characters showing up in incorrect order? or Arabic as well? Why do you need the list processing fixed if it's just an attempted hack?

Comment: No, Latin characters aren't the problem. The Arabic words in the sentence are reversed, in the sense "I am reading" is written as  "reading. am I" by Python. I don't know how to fix this. I attempted to fix it by putting all the words into a list yet the characters become corrupted once I retrieve them from that list--it may be the case that Python lists don't support UTF-8.

Comment: After doing some checking, it looks like Python doesn't natively perform BIDI text rendering. I suspect that for writing into an XML file it will work OK, since it internally holds the code points of the string in the correct order. It just might be a pain for debugging. If you try writing out the text into your XML format and open it with a BIDI-aware program (like most web browsers), what do you get?

Comment: @Blckknght I haven't tried that out yet, will write something up and comment back. Thanks.

Comment: @Blckknght, you know what, you were right. It looks totally normal once you do that. The problem only appears to exist in IDLE. If you want to submit that as the answer below, I'll be glad to `accept` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python only poorly supports BIDI rendering internally. That is, it doesn't fully implement the [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

But, this won't matter unless you're doing text layout directly in Python. For the project you have desribed (reading a file with some BIDI text and outputting another file with the same text), Python will do just fine. That's because the ordering of the text in the files (both input and output) will reflect the semantic ordering, not the direction the text should appear on an end user's screen. If you produce an XML file and open it with a BIDI capable reader (like most web browsers), you should see the text displayed in the right order.

For your reference, there are also a few modules that add better support for bidirectional text rendering to Python. One is [python-bidi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi), which apparently works pretty well for most languages with right to left text, but doesn't deal with Arabic letter shaping properly yet. Another is [pyfribidi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfribidi/) a binding for the [GNU fribidi](http://fribidi.org/) library, which apparently is only easily compilable on Linux (and perhaps other Unix-like OSs). I've not used either of those, so I can't offer a personal recommendation.